# Debugging TensorFlow tests: pdb or gdb?

Tags: python, gdb, tensorflow, pdb

I am debugging decode_raw_op_test from TensorFlow. The test file is written in python however it executes code from underlying C++ files.

Using pdb, I could debug python test file however it doesn't recognize c++ file. Is there a way in which we can debug underlying c++ code?

(I tried using gdb on decode_raw_op_test but it gives "File not in executable format: File format not recognized")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debugging a mixed Python and C++ program is tricky. You can use `gdb` to debug the C++ parts of TensorFlow, however. There are two main ways to do this:

1. Run `python` under `gdb`, rather than the test script itself. Let's say that your test script is in `bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/decode_raw_op_test`. You would run the following command:

   ```
   $ gdb python bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/decode_raw_op_test
   (gdb) run
   ```

   Note that `gdb` does not have great support for debugging the Python parts of the code. I'd recommend narrowing down the test case that you run to a single, simple test, and setting a breakpoint on a TensorFlow C API method, such as `TF_Run`, which is the main entry point from Python into C++ in TensorFlow.
2. Attach `gdb` to a running process. You can get the process ID of the Python test using `ps` and then run (where `$PID` is the process ID):

   ```
   $ gdb -p $PID
   ```

   You will probably need to arrange for your Python code to block so that there's time to attach. Calling the `raw_input()` function is an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Could debug using below steps:

```
gdb python
```

then on gdb prompt, type

```
run bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/decode_raw_op_test
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on mrry's answer, in today's TF2 environment, the main entry point would be TFE_Execute, this should be where you add the breakpoint.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).